# ODE Rumour Spread

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> A certain person starts a rumour in a small town. The number of people who have heard the
>   rumour, $R(t)$, is given by
>   $$
> \frac{\text d R}{\text d t} = KR \left(1300 - R\right)
> $$
>   where $K$ is a positive constant, and 1300 is the number of residents in that small town.
>
> By regarding this equation as a Bernoulli equation, find $R(t)$.

This is my current working, I have no idea how the answer got $\frac1R=\frac1{1300}+Ce^{-1300Kt}$

Where did my t go to?

Followed by solving the equation to get $\frac1R=\frac1{1300}+\frac{1299}{1300}e^{-1300Kt}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write your equation as
\begin{align}
\frac{dR}{kR(1300-R)} = dt 
\end{align}
and integrate!  [I figure out you did typo on your notes!]

And then managing $t$ then you will get the answer.

---

About @deviljones comment, try $x=\frac{1}{R}$[since $R=R(t)$, $x=x(t)$], then 
\begin{align}
-\frac{dx}{1300kx-k} = dt 
\end{align}
after integration you have 
\begin{align}
ln(k-1300kx) = -1300kt + C 
\end{align}
Then expressing in terms of $x=\frac{1}{R}$, you get what you want.

Comment: Same answer, same time ! Cheers.

Comment: But I am supposed to solve it using the  Bernoulli equation method, which is what I am doing, but I have no idea where did the answer get the letter t from

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

It would be easier to solve
$$\frac 1{t'}=k R(1300-R)$$ Reverse it, use partial fraction decomposition to get $t(R)$ and then $R(t)$.

Comment: But I am supposed to solve it using the  Bernoulli equation method, which is what I am doing, but I have no idea where did the answer get the letter t from